# PlayFramework 2.X routing to generated content

Tags: java, html, playframework-2.3

I have a process within my play app that generates a text file.  I would like to copy this text file to a directory where i can then view it from a static route. 
In production mode,  the public assets folder is jar'd up,   Is there a directory I can place my files into where I can route to them in prod mode.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a site for discussion of coding.  For best results, please provide the code you're currently running, what you want it to do, and what it's actually doing.

Comment: With the `Assets` router, no. You would need something custom.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for confirming m-z,  I ended up rolling my own solution which is hopefully secure....
In my Global application class ,  I store a file location, which is then accessible by my controllers.  The controllers simply read the 
file(s) into a Buffered REader, then spit them back out.
using OK.sendFile(string).

thanks ,